# IIS 6.0 and Windows Server 2003 - Intranet changed address

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, intranet

Firstly, I’m not completely familiar with IIS 6.0.

Anyway, my company has a server running Windows Server 2003. A few months ago, I set up a company intranet and everything has been running smoothly since.

To get to the intranet, all the users had to do was go to http://192.168.1.5 in their browsers. This morning, however, when users were trying to reach this address, the connection would time out every time. Upon investigation, I found that users could alternatively access the intranet from http://192.168.1.13.

Is there a reason for the change? I’m almost certain no changes were made to the server or IIS, so why the sudden change in addresses?

Will this happen again in a few months?

Comment: Can you paste in the output from `ipconfig /all`?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the IP address on the server changed. Did the server reboot over the weekend?

Ask whoever admins your internal DNS to setup an entry for http://intranet to go to http://servername and/or set a static IP on the server.

Comment: Thank you for your response, BoBo. This is where I become confused, as the server was not restarted. I just want to figure out why the IP address changed, presumably on it's own.

Comment: Windows logs?If you assign a static Ip and/or add the DNS, the why becomes acedemic.

Answer (score 0):

DHCP-assigned addresses can expire, your DHCP server (maybe a network device in this case) may have reset if your sure that your server didn't.

If you're using a server as a web server it's definitely a good idea to be sure it has a staic IP or a reservation set in the DHCP server.

If for some reason you don't want to do that, then you could use the servers name if DNS is set up properly, or you could even go so far as to assign a CNAME.